# Modal com Iframe

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Possuo uma tela de login, após logar, o conteúdo que tenho se abre em modais, e ao clicar nelas (abrem por `iframe`), se perde a sessão de login...

Como solucionar este problema?

Comment: como a sessão do usuário está sendo armazenada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse iframe que se abre, fica no mesmo dominio que seu site?

Você está dando um session_start() nas páginas que são abertas dentro do iframe?

[Isso pode te ajudar.](http://blog.vilourenco.com.br/php-trabalhando-com-sessions/)

Comment: Obrigado, era isto mesmo.

Comment: @Eduardo Saute, Se ajudei, marca como resposta certa :) Abraços.

Comment: @Alex Juchem Se possível transcreva a solução para o post, assim evitamos link´s quebrados e que a informação seja perdida.